# Passing a string in Process::Start

Tags: c++, .net, string, c++-cli, process.start

I run successfully:

```
Process::Start("C:\\Users\\Demetres\\Desktop\\JoypadCodesApplication.exe");
```

from a Windows Forms application (visual c++) and as expected, I got 2 programs running simultaneously. My questions is:

Can I pass a string -indicating the file name- to the `Process::Start` method? I tried:

```
std::string str="C:\\Users\\Demetres\\Desktop\\JoypadCodesApplication.exe";
Process::Start("%s", str);
```

but failed. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of dozens of questions: how to convert std::string to System::String^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually need to marshal to a `System::String^` for passing an argument.
You can even marshal directly from a `std::string` to a `System::String^`.

```
///marshal_as<type>(to_marshal)
///marshal_context ctx; ctx.marshal_as<const char *>(to_marshal)
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_atl.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

Process::Start(marshal_as<String^>(str));
```

But in this case, you can just use a `String^` instead:

```
String^ str = L"path to file";
Process::Start(str);
```

When you are working with C++/CLI, you either need to marshal back and forth or use the right data type from the start for how you want to use it.

[MSDN: Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`Process::Start` expects a `String^` and you are attempting to pass it a `std::string`.  It does not have a variadric version, and does not know what a `std::string` is.  To pass the value from a `std::string`, you must marshal it:

```
std::string str("Some Path");
Process::Start(marshal_as<String^>(str));
```

Comment: Unlikely, it still gives me an error, as image indicates. Seems to me that the fault is not actually there.

Comment: @dempap No, the fault is there (I did forget about the marshalling issue though).